# Why didn't Spider-Man wear armour all the time?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers, spider-man, avengers-vs-x-men

Spider-Man has an new suit of armour that he's had ready for a long time, and he finally gets to show it off in The Amazing Spider-Man #683. Sometime before or after those events he's in AvX #1. Regardless of how those events are chronologically linked, I've gotten the impression he's worn armour before. Why not wear it all the time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Spider-Man has, for the bulk of his career, avoided using armor for a couple of reasons, primarily, with his powers being based in mobility and agility, coupled with a short-term precognition, it made more sense to be "light and fast" dodging damage than trying to "tank the damage" using armor.

1. He depended on his short-term precognitive ability (commonly called his "spider-sense") to avoid danger. It would alert him to any attack that could conceivably harm him. Only a few of his foes possessed the ability to avoid triggering his spider-sense, Venom and Carnage being two of them.
2. His acrobatic fighting style, which was self-taught, depended on his natural flexibility, agility and ability to cling to walls. With the creation of his web shooters (or natural web making abilities, depending on which universe you are in) he was able to fight in a variety of fashions creating armor from webbing when he needed it.
3. He was better served by retaining his natural speed and agility in combat. While Spider-Man could take a punch by most of his rogue's gallery, he preferred to avoid damage, rather than taking it. His incredible reflex speed has served him in combat more than nearly any other fighting asset. Coupled with his strength, he is a formidable enemy in hand to hand combat.

Once Spider-Man started hanging out with the Avengers, it was decided he might need to augment his natural abilities with armors designed by Stark which gave him a wider array of options in his superhero arsenal (and to offset the loss of his spider-senses).

His latest armor incorporates the designs of the three armored suits including the Iron Spider rig, the stealth suit and the unstable molecule design incorporated into a single suit. This suit also has been upgraded to enhance his considerable physical abilities increasing his strength, speed and agility. His spider-sense had been lost and whether it will return is still unknown.

[image: Spider-Man Armors - Iron Spider Rig (Tony Stark), Stealth Suit (Peter Parker), Future Foundation's unstable molecule suit (Reed Richards)]

*Spider-Man Armors - Iron Spider Rig (Tony Stark), Stealth Suit (Peter Parker), Future Foundation's unstable molecule suit (Reed Richards)*

**Spider-Man will be getting a new suit of armor starting in The [Amazing Spider-Man #682](http://www.digitalspy.com/comics/news/a363918/marvel-unveils-new-spider-man-armor.html). How this suit will work in relationship to his powers, and who the manufacturer is, has yet to be revealed.**

[image: New Spider Armor - Amazing Spider-Man #682]

Comment: Stark's probably the only person in Marvel capable of making armour that wouldn't slow Spider-man down badly.  (The armour was originally something of a plot point up to and during Civil War.)

Comment: I was under the impression that Spider-man wasn't slowed down by his armour at all...or else he wouldn't want to wear it.

Comment: He has had several armored costumes, each an order of magnitude better than the one before it. The first Iron Spider outfit gave him extensive capabilities but slowed him down a bit. The second suit was designed by him and did not slow him at all, but was not nearly as sophisticated as Stark's. The third armor incorporated all the best of all of the armors and improved both his physical abilities and technologies of the Iron Spider rig.

Comment: But, I assume, slowed him down enough that it was an option all the time.

Comment: Why does spiderman wearing armour counteract his spider sense?

Comment: It didn't necessarily counteract it. But it did slow him down sufficiently that he could not take advantage of it. Like knights of old, armor offers protection when you can't avoid being hit, with the understanding you will be slower while wearing it. Spider-Man's precognitive ability allowed him to avoid danger only if he were fast enough to take advantage of it...

Answer (score -1):

Funny you should ask,because in the all-new all-different amazing spiderman comic book line he upgrades his suit to be a liquid metal suit with different types of technology.

Comment: Sure, but why does he not wear it all the time?

Answer (score -3):

The Spider Armour mark 2 didn't slow him down, nor did the Ends of the Earth or the Iron Spider. In fact, none of his armours slow him down, except for one that did in the 90's when he made this bulky silver spider armour mark 1. Since then he has improved and made the Spider Armour mark 2. That is the one with the yellow spider and black round. It is extremely light weight, compact, tight, and flexible. The reason why he dosen't use those sometimes because his skin tight costume can fit under his cloths and he didn't need it with the threats he was facing. Spiderman didn't need those costumes they just helped.

Comment: This could probably be expanded into a full answer, but currently feels like it's more of a comment/response to Thaddeus's answer.